# Searching for title of fantasy novel including harpies

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

I read a children's fantasy book in the 80's that had illustrations. It was about a boy and possibly a girl in a magical forest. There were harpies that menaced them. Does anyone know what book that was?

Comment: When I hear "children's fantasy book" and "fantasy novel", I think of two different things. Was this more of a story/picture-book, or an actual novel?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronia_the_Robber's_Daughter

Comment: It was a shortish novel with some illustrations.It contained an image of harpies.

Comment: Can you say anything more about the illustrations?  Were they in color or more of a pen-and-ink type things, particularly realistic or more stylized?

Comment: Could this be the same as [Story about teen boy being harassed by harpy on trip to castle](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95210/story-about-teen-boy-being-harassed-by-harpy-on-trip-to-castle)?

Answer (score 6):

80's, boy, girl, forest, menacing harpies. Not much to go on, but could easily have been one of  [Piers Anthony's many Xanth novels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth) which filled shelves in bookstores from the late 70's on. There was one in particular with a nasty harpy in it back in 84 or so, but it's been so long, and there are so many Xanth novels that I couldn't pin it down.

Comment: *"and there are so many Xanth novels"* I'm pretty sure I've seen an inductive proof that they are countably infinite.

Comment: The covers of Xanth books frequently feature harpies but I don't believe that any of them (with the exception of the illustrated guide to xanth) are actually illustrated in the sense of having pictures on the inside. Can you provide an example of one that has illustrations?

Comment: It isn't one of those novels. however the Xanth novels sound interesting. I might read one.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might well be [The Seventh Princess by Nick Sullivan](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1280058.The_Seventh_Princess).  This is a short middle-grade story about a girl who is transported to a fantasy land, where she is called a princess. The six princesses before her have all been transformed into Harpies. First published by Scholastic in 1983.

I don't remember the story having a boy, but it does have a dwarf.

Comment: In the novel the kids belonged in that world. They weren't transported there. I don't think it is 'The Seventh princess'. The title might have included the words; 'woods','forest', 'world' or something along those lines. I'm not sure of that.

Comment: I think the illustrations were black and white and kind of creepy looking. I don't think there were lots of illustrations. They were stylized illustrations and perhaps a bit sketchy.

Answer (score 2):

Is it [Ronia The Robber's Daughter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronia_the_Robber%27s_Daughter)? That was a favorite of mine growing up.

> Birk and Ronia run away to the **woods**, where they live in a cave and experience several harrowing adventures with the wood's indigenous wildlife, including trolls, forest gnomes, and **harpies**.

Comment: Welcome to [Scifi.SE]! It would help if you explain a bit in what ways "Ronia the Robber's Daughter" matches the description given in the question.

Comment: Apparently it does include scary harpies: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/19314.Ronia_the_Robber_s_Daughter: "The characters are great and the harpies scared me when I was young" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronia_the_Robber%27s_Daughter I'm going to have to dig this one up, it sounds fun.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be Tamora Pierce's [The Immortals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Immortals_%28series%29) series. Set in the same world as her Alanna books.