# Story about teen boy being harassed by harpy on trip to castle

Tags: story-identification, books

There is a book that I have vague memories of reading years ago. I can't really recall much about the plot except that the a teen boy was on a quest or journey of some sort. At some point a harpy is harassing him while he is out in the open area.

I remember bits and pieces but I recall some sort of separate world that he travels through with air elements (it seems they had actual names), I also recall either an ice castle or crystal castle. There was something within that castle.

I don't know if over the last 20+ years I have combined a couple books. I only recall reading two sci fi books that officially come from that section of the store and they were *The Clerics Quintet* (which I read about 9 years ago) and *A Spell for Chameleon* which I read during the time of this weird memory.

I keep thinking it mentioned '**chaos**' but I have searched and none sound familiar.

Comment: The part with the harpy vaguely stirs my memory as being from one of the Xanth books, but I can't say I recognize any of the other bits you mentioned.

Comment: Could this be the same as [Searching for title of fantasy novel including harpies](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37698/searching-for-title-of-fantasy-novel-including-harpies)?

Comment: There are several things in my memory that is in the only book in the Xanth series I've  read (also currently rereading it). I wish I could figure out what the other is. I know that years ago when I read it I was VERY ill. That's why I'm wondering if my child imagination took over or if during my illness I ran a temperature causing odd dreams. I also read anything I could get my hands on too. I have a habit of reading many books at a time. If anyone thinks of anything with air elements or ice elements, post it. The harpy is in the Xanth novel I have figured that out. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any chance this might be one of the early Percy Jackson books?

Comment: I will look into it and see.

Answer (score 2):

Except for the harpy, this sounds a great deal like [Sorceror's Son](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorcerer%27s_Son) and the sequel [The Crystal Palace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crystal_Palace_(novel)).  You may have read them together in the omnibus edition.

- IIRC, the protagonist is in his late teens in the first story.
- For part of the first book, the protagonist lives in the demon realm with the assistance of air demons, aka elementals.  The demons all have names.  In the second book, he travels through the demon world several times, again with the help of an air demon.
- A crystal palace is central to the plot of the second novel.

You might also remember

- Him teaching the demons to swordfight?
- Using spiderwebs to communicate?
- The use of magic rings to trap demons?
- The enchanted mirror he and his friend craft, which shows him the young girl trapped in the crystal palace?

Comment: Even if this is not the right answer, I commend you for so much detail, including possible additional scenes to match against. It may help with others.